# Matlab: how to optimize a code with a lot of expressions

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a array of strings TrajCompact (106x1). 
For every strings I want to find '00','11','22','33','44','12','21' etc and count them. I create a code that give me a right answer but it's not efficienty: it's long and not smart. My code is

```
for k=1:106
%% Determinazione elementi diagonale matrice
matchstarts_00(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k,1), '0.+?0'); %for '00'
matchcounts_00(k) = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_00(k));

matchstarts_11(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k,1), '1.+?1'); %for '11'
matchcounts_11(k) = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_11(k));

matchstarts_22(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k,1), '2.+?2'); %for '11'
matchcounts_22(k) = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_22(k));

matchstarts_33(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k,1), '3.+?3'); %for '11'
matchcounts_33(k) = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_33(k));

matchstarts_44(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k,1), '4.+?4'); %for '11'
matchcounts_44(k) = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_44(k));
end

count_00=sum(matchcounts_00);    
count_11=sum(matchcounts_11);
count_22=sum(matchcounts_22);
count_33=sum(matchcounts_33);
count_44=sum(matchcounts_44);
```

Can you give me suggest to optimize it! Thanks

Comment: Afraid I don't know matlab but just at a conceptual level, this code requires multiple passes through the same string for each individual regexp call. An optimal solution algorithmically (and also memory-wise if the strings are relatively large) is going to be able to find all these matches in a single pass through a string, but afraid I don't know the means to do that through the matlab API/language. Hopefully someone can pitch in here.

Comment: thanks for the suggest! I try different ways but I have once again problems! :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp` accepts multiple strings to match against if you specify them as a cell array. In fact, you're already passing it a one-element cell array by passing it `TrajCompact(k,1)` rather than `TrajCompact{k,1}`. If you had used the latter, you would have been able to just use `numel` rather than `cellfun` to get the counts. But since you actually do have multiple strings to match against you can do them all in one go:

```
matchstarts_00 = regexp(TrajCompact, '0.+?0');
matchcounts_00 = cellfun(@numel, matchstarts_00);
```

You can also vectorize the operation for each regular expression that you want to test, but because you want a result for every combination of an element of `TrajCompact` and a given regular expression, you'll need to do this with a loop.

Your examples only create counts for pairs of indices on the diagonal of a matrix, but your question suggests you want all pairs of indices for a matrix. Either way, it's tidy to set up arrays with one element for each regular expression, and one array for each digit, stored as a cell array. For all combinations (including '12' '21', etc):

```
[digits{1:2}] = ndgrid(0:4);
```

or for diagonals:

```
[digits{1:2}] = deal(0:4);
```

You can then loop over that array to assemble the regular expression for each combination and get the counts. I'm assuming the "starts" array doesn't actually need to be recalled, so rather than storing that in a cell array I'm overwriting the same variable for each iteration, but it should be clear how you would store that in a cell array as well if need be.

```
matchcounts = cell(size(digits{1}));
for k = 1:numel(matchcounts)
    matchstarts = regexp(TrajCompact, sprintf('%d.+?%d', digits{1}(k), digits{2}(k)));
    matchcounts{k} = cellfun(@numel,matchstarts);
end
```

Comment: I have an other question: i want to use the same code to find also the same elements but inside (): example (11), (12), (13), etc. I try to modify sprintf in different ways: for example  matchstarts = regexp(TrajCompact, sprintf('(%d.+?%d)', digits{1}(k), digits{2}(k))); but the code doesn't give the right answer. I read information about sprintf and it doesn't support brackets... how can i solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: `sprintf` isn't the important function here. It's just used here to build the regular expression string that goes into `regexp` using the numeric values in `digits`. So your example above will result in `regexp(TrajCompact, '(0.+?0)')`.

The problem is that `(` and `)` are special characters in regular expressions. To match them as literal characters they need to be escaped with a preceding ``\`` in the regular expression. But since ``\`` is also a special character in `sprintf` patterns, you need to double escape it so `sprintf` ignores the slashes and `regexp` sees them: `\\(%d.+?%d\\)`

Comment: Thanks! Yesterday i have tried only with one '\' before brackets: two solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

So you can use `findstr` instead of a `regex` over each one; `findstr` is actually just a regex, but it is a also a Matlab function - so you can use it in parallel (which basically removes the need of the `for` loop). There are a few ways to go:

say your Cell Array is:

```
Test = {'020103101adfiohjas','020123101a01dfasad'}
```

method 1:

```
tic
A = cellfun(@(x) size(findstr(x,'01'),2), Test, 'UniformOutput', 0)
total = sum(cell2mat(A))
toc

Elapsed time is 0.015609 seconds.
```

method 2:

```
T = char([Test{:}])
tic
total = size(findstr(T,'01'),2)
toc

Elapsed time is 0.007199 seconds.
```

Method 2 requires you to collapse all your cells into 1 big cell, and uses findstr to quickly find the number of '01' in the Char Array.

Method 1 is much more powerful, you can use it to obtain all the indexes of '01' and etc, but judging by tictoc, method 2 is faster.

Comment: thanks for your suggest! Your methods are for the case in which the 2 digits are consecutive, but I want to find also the digits that are not consecutive. For example in this sting '021(23)(12)32131231(32)(13)(23)1321(32)303231213231(23)' I have to find 7 '01' while with your methods I find 0 '01'. :(

Comment: wait, how did you find 7? there are only 2 zeros right?

Comment: excuse me I find 1 '01' and with your method 0. I made a mistake writing.